# Android databinding (3.0.0-alpha4) not working for include tags

Tags: android, data-binding

I have the following layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable name="foo" type="Bar" />
    </data>
        .
        .
        .
<layout>
```

And I used the include layout as the follow:

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/id"
        layout="@layout/foo"
        app:foo="@{foo}" />
```

When using android databinding 2.3.3 (`kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.3`) everything works fine, but when I update to the currently version (`kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0-alpha4"`) I got the following error:

```
[kapt] An exception occurred: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Exception while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:149)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:347)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:336)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:387)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:784)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:811)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:783)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:971)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:851)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:777)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:971)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:851)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:327)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:viewModel' with parameter type com.ebanx.go.modules.statement.DepositItemViewModel on com.ebanx.go.databinding.StatementItemBinding. file:/Users/guilherme/Documents/ego-android/app/src/main/res/layout/item_group_deposit.xml loc:22:29 - 22:37 ****\ data binding error ****
```

It seems to be a bug in the databinding library, but I was hoping if someone already has a workaround for it.